# allow user to change text in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello guys I am trying to create a function in js that will allow user to edit a text inside a div. here's my view:

```
@endsection
 <div onload="InitEditable ();" id="content-link2"></div>
@show
```

Here's my HTML file loaded inside div id="content-link2"::

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Template 1</title>
  <link href="http://localhost/fyproject/public/templates/css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>
<body class="pink">
<div  contenteditable="true" id="content" class="draggable ui-widget-content pink"><p>hello</p></div>
<div id="comments">
<form name="forma">
<textarea name="commentUser" id="commentUser" cols="40" rows="5">
Comments here...
</textarea><br>
<input type="submit" value="Ready!" onClick="writeComment(e);" />
</div>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

JS::

```
var editorDoc;
 function InitEditable () {
var editor = document.getElementsById('content-link2');
 editorDoc = editor.contentWindow.document;          
            var editorBody = editorDoc.div;

                // turn off spellcheck
            if ('spellcheck' in editorBody) {    // Firefox
                editorBody.spellcheck = false;
            }

            if ('contentEditable' in editorBody) {
                    // allow contentEditable
                editorBody.contentEditable = true;
            }
            else {  // Firefox earlier than version 3
                if ('designMode' in editorDoc) {
                        // turn on designMode
                    editorDoc.designMode = "on";                
                }
            }
        }
```

I will explain a process. Customer clicks on image which loads a html file inside a div. I then allow user to move div around which is with html file and now I want to allow customer to change text inside that div

[image: So I want to change text inside a red div]

Comment: You need to provide a [minimal complete and verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of **only the relevant code**.  Right now you've included far too much code, and have not narrowed it down to the "edit text inside div" portion.

Comment: done. I think only this is needed, i have included html to show what should be able to be edited

Comment: there are not such property as `div` in `document`, you need to call `document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0]` if you want to access first div on the page or if you want to use jQuery `$('div')[0]`

Comment: What if I would like to access all div inside a document? Therefore being able to edit more than 1 div?

Comment: like this??  `function InitEditable () {
var editor = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
 editorDoc = editor.contentWindow.document;          
            var editorBody = editorDoc.$('div')[0];`

Comment: Right I've got it working however for some reason it now moves me to another page while it should do it on the same page

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try `contenteditable`.

For example:

```html
<div contenteditable="true">Type to edit...</div>
```

As it says in [MDN  - Making Content Editable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content):

> In HTML, any element can be editable. By using some JavaScript event
>   handlers, you can transform your web page into a full and fast rich
>   text editor. This article provides some information about this
>   functionality.

Comment: This is what I am using at the moment but I also have to implement a feature to save changes of that div (html page) in database

Comment: Why not use the web standard - get() and send it to the php file. Once there, tell php to access the database and write tables there?